# Regex to match fields separated by underscores

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to match patterns beginning with:

```
i%_%_%_%_c$_p$
```

Where

```
% is a number with 1 to 3 digits
$ is a 2-digit number
Other characters are literal
```

Example I'm trying to solve:

```
ex <- 'i192_168_10_1_c01_p89_some_other_stuff'
grepl('some_pattern', ex)
```

I've gotten this far:

```
grepl('^i[0-9]{1-3}', ex)
TRUE
```

But when I try to include an underscore before the next set of numbers, I get:

```
grepl('^i[0-9]{1-3}_', ex)
FALSE
```

I've tried all manner of other things I've found while searching, but none of it seems to help me make any sense of this, though it appears like it should be a simple match.  Nevertheless, I'm inexperienced with regex.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `grepl('^i[0-9]{1,3}_', ex)`

Comment: @akrun I feel especially foolish for having used a hyphen instead of a comma within that range.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
^i(?:\d{1,3}_){4}c\d{2}_p\d{2}
```

See details for the regex (with your provided example) here: https://regex101.com/r/iF1jN9/1

```
ex <- 'i192_168_10_1_c01_p89_some_other_stuff'
grepl('^i(?:\\d{1,3}_){4}c\\d{2}_p\\d{2}', ex)
# [1] TRUE
```

I don't know if you wanted to match whatever came next:

```
_some_other_stuff
```

If that's the case, you can add `.*$` to the regex at the end.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just a note for other people looking to use this in R, be sure to double escape (e.g. \\d) since you have to escape once for R and again for regex.  That's why I avoided using them in the first place.  Nevertheless, this was a great answer.

Comment: Good point, I just presented the regex in PCRE syntax, it has to be escaped in some cases depending on the language.